# Is there a info function for numpy arrays?

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am looking for some function, that returns the most important information about a [numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).
Often, I print arrays and get the completely wrong impression about them, as the string cast just shows the most outer elements.

Practically I step into the following issues from time to time:

- Just the outer elements are nan, but it contans non-nan entries as well
- There is a nan value hidden somewhere, making it necessary to use nan-save functions (for instance [np.nanmean()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) instead of [np.mean()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html))
- `np.inf` occurs, which prevents any simple overview of the value range for finite values

The `pandas` library has for instance the [DataFrame.info()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) method. Is there a pendant in numpy?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I use a **workaround** giving me results like

```
np.ndarray of shape (5, 11)
        ---
        dtype: float64
        contains non-finite elements: nan, inf
        ---
        mean: 8.375849056603775
        min: 0.0
        max: 16.74
        ---
        std: 4.9867932880730885
        mad: 6.434493628314312
        ---
values:
[[ 0.    0.31  0.62  0.93  1.24  1.55  1.86  2.17  2.48  2.79  3.1 ]
 [ 3.41  3.72  4.03  4.34  4.65  4.96  5.27   inf  5.89  6.2   6.51]
 [ 6.82  7.13  7.44  7.75  8.06  8.37  8.68  8.99  9.3   9.61  9.92]
 [10.23 10.54   nan 11.16 11.47 11.78 12.09 12.4  12.71 13.02 13.33]
 [13.64 13.95 14.26 14.57 14.88 15.19 15.5  15.81 16.12 16.43 16.74]]
```

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.robust import mad

def ndarray_info(arr, verbose=2):
    """returns extensive information about an np.ndarray as string"""

    finArr = arr.flatten()
    finArr = finArr[np.isfinite(finArr)]

    info = ''
    info += f'np.ndarray of shape {arr.shape}\n'
    info += '\t---\n'
    info += f'\tdtype: {arr.dtype}\n'




    info += f'\tcontains non-finite elements: '
    nonFinElLst = []
    if np.isnan(arr).any():
        nonFinElLst += ['nan']
    if np.isinf(arr).any():
        nonFinElLst += ['inf']
    if len(nonFinElLst) > 0:
        info += ', '.join(nonFinElLst) + '\n'
    else:
        info += '--\n'

    info += '\t---\n'
    info += f'\tmean: {np.mean(finArr)}\n'
    info += f'\tmin: {np.min(finArr)}\n'
    info += f'\tmax: {np.max(finArr)}\n'


    if verbose >=1:
        info += '\t---\n'
        info += f'\tstd: {np.std(finArr)}\n'
        info += f'\tmad: {mad(finArr)}\n'

    if verbose >=2:
        info += '\t---\n'
        info += 'values:\n' + str(arr) + '\n'


    return info

arr= np.arange(0,17,.31).reshape(5,11)
arr[3,2] = np.nan
arr[1,7] = np.inf
print(ndarray_info(arr))
```

Comment: That's a lot more statistics than I see in a `df.info()`

Comment: True! I think I want a combination of `pandas.DataFrame.info()` and `pandas.DataFrame.describe()` to be more precise.